# Subqueries with different universes

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle DB and I need to run a select with sub selects, however, none of them share the same table universe, therefore, I would need to do something like this:

```
SELECT  (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   user_table
) AS tot_user,
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   cat_table
) AS tot_cat,
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   course_table
) AS tot_course
```

I know this is possible at other databases but I need something like this for Oracle.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

To make this work in oracle, add `from dual` to the end:

```
SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM   user_table
        ) AS tot_user,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM   cat_table
        ) AS tot_cat,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM   course_table
        ) AS tot_course
FROM dual;
```

A database independent way of writing the query is:

```
select tot_user, tot_cat, tot_course
from (SELECT COUNT(*) as tot_user
      FROM   user_table
     ) u cross join
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as tot_cat
      FROM   cat_table
     ) c cross join
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as tot_course
      FROM   course_table
     ) ct;
```